# Tabs in Android UI: Are tabs just to toggle display of different contents, or can we perform long operations on the click of tab header?

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

The idea I have of tabs is that they are used semantically to display different contents on the same part of the screen.

Now I think it implies that all the data that needs to be displayed should be there, and only a  display of that tab's contents should take place when the user clicks a tab-header.

From [Android Design guide](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html),

> Fixed tabs display all items concurrently.

If I am understanding this correctly (I am assuming concurrently means sharing the same itme), all items should be there, and the user clicking the tab headers should just toggle the display.

**But does it make sense to do an internet search, and make a web service call etc., on the click of a tab-header, so that the response from the web-service etc. is displayed in the tab?**

Comment: *But does it make sense...* - how do you plan to do otherwise if the tab content is not something trivial like plain text?

Comment: May be in that case they would not be tabs but buttons, below which there would be a container which displays the contents? 
Should I take this as an answer, that yes it will OK and not a coding bad-practice if I call a web-service on click on a tab header?

Comment: It's expected by the user that the tab content will most likely not be available right away, in order to indicate this you may want to place a loading indicator in the content of that tab. This way, when the user selects the tab you'll start the background job and also show a progress indicator in the content area for that tab so the user knows that something is loading.